# Creating an associative array from a js file as opposed to a xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have been working on a function `getxml` which created an associative array of all the albums/tracks it found in an xml file:

```
function XMLload() {
    jQuery.post(url, function(data) {
        getxml(data);
    }, 'xml');
}

function dataFromTag(node, t) {
    var d = node.getElementsByTagName(t);
    if (d.length == 0) return ('');
    return (d[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
}

jQuery(document).ready(XMLload);

var url = 'music.xml';

function getxml(xmldoc) {
xmlalbums = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('album');

for (var i = 0; i < xmlalbums.length; i++) {
    title = dataFromTag(xmlalbums[i], 'title');
    artist = dataFromTag(xmlalbums[i], 'artist');
    artwork = dataFromTag(xmlalbums[i], 'artwork');

    var xmltracks = xmlalbums[i].getElementsByTagName('track');

    var tracks = []

    for (var j = 0; j < xmltracks.length; j++) {
        song = dataFromTag(xmltracks[j], 'title');
        mp3 = dataFromTag(xmltracks[j], 'mp3');
        tracks[song] = mp3;
    }
    albumlist[title] = [artist, artwork, tracks];
}

// call pageLoad();
pageLoad();
}
```

The xml file was in the following format:

```
<albums>
    <album>
        <title></title>
        <artist></artist>
        <artwork></artwork>
        <track>
            <title></title>
            <mp3></mp3>
        </track>
        <track>
            <title></title>
            <mp3></mp3>
        </track>
        <track>
            <title></title>
            <mp3></mp3>
        </track>
        <track>
            <title></title>
            <mp3></mp3>
        </track>
    </album>
</albums>
```

I am now trying to do the same with a ***.js** file with the following details. But I have no idea how to reinterpret the code, to avoid changing the rest of my code. Any idea how I can accomplish this? The js file is in the below format:

```
var albums=
[
    {   "title":"",
        "artist":"",
        "artwork":"",
        "tracks":[
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
        ]
    },
    {   "title":"",
        "artist":"",
        "artwork":"",
        "tracks":[
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
        ]
    },

]
```

Comment: Isn't that what JSON is for?

Comment: How would I accomplish the code reinterpretation in JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var albums` has a couple of issues (extra commas, check http://jsonlint.com/ to validate it). But besides that it is a valid JSON object.

```
var albums=
[
    {   "title":"",
        "artist":"",
        "artwork":"",
        "tracks":[
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""}
        ]
    },
    {   "title":"",
        "artist":"",
        "artwork":"",
        "tracks":[
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
            {"title":"","mp3":".mp3",
            "lyrics":""},
        ]
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) {
    title = albums[i].title;
    artist = albums[i].artist;
    artwork = albums[i].artwork;

    var tracks = []

    for (var j = 0; j < albums[i].tracks.length; j++) {
        song = albums[i].tracks[j].title;
        mp3 = albums[i].tracks[j].mp3;
        tracks[song] = mp3;
    }
    albumlist[title] = [artist, artwork, tracks];
}
```